# Shortcut for jumping between words in Sublime Text 2 wanted

Tags: macos, shortcut, sublimetext

I want to jump between words in a text editor (e.g. Sublime Text 2). In Windows, I can use Ctrl-Left or Ctrl-Right. What is the shortcut on Mac?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use Sublime Text 2 (version 2.0.2, Build 2221) under OS X 10.8.5 and I move from word to word by pressing the option key and left or right arrow key.

<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>

<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>

These are the [OS X standard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT201236) so most apps that use the standard SDK behave similarly.

Comment: Works also on OS X 10.11.4 and Sublime Text 2.0.2, tested with Build 2221.

Comment: @bmike, Thanks for making it a hyperlink not just an URL! :-)